# __del__ does not work if the instance is recorded in a class dictionnary

Tags: python, class, python-3.x, dictionary

I want to register every instances on my class in a dictionary, keys are one of the parameter.

This seems to work, but the `__del__` function fails. 
Here is the code :

```
class Test(object):
    instances = {}

    def __init__(self, id):
        self.id = id

    def launch(self):
        print("launch")
        Test.instances[self.id] = self

    def __del__(self):
        print("del")
        del Test.instances[self.id]
```

And here are the different outputs I get:

```
>>> a = Test(25)
>>> del a
del
>>> a = Test(25)
>>> a.launch()
launch
>>> del a
>>>
```

I don't understand why this is happening, does someone has a suggestion?

Comment: `del` and `__del__` have very little to do with each other; `__del__` certainly isn't for overloading the `del` operator or anything like that.

Comment: You probably want to use a `weakref.WeakValueDictionary` for `Test.instances`. See the documentation about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`__del__` is only called once there are no more references to the object in the code.  It *isn't* (necessarily) called when the `del` keyword is used on an object.

When you `launch` a `Test` instance, you end up with 2 references -- `a` and an extra reference in the `Test.instances` dict.  Doing `del a` only deletes the reference `a`.  The `Test.instances` reference is still hanging around so `__del__` won't be called.

A (possibly) better way to manage references to objects is to store `weakref` to objects.  In this case, you'd probably make `Test.instances` a [`weakref.WeakValueDictionary`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/weakref.html#weakref.WeakValueDictionary).

Comment: I understand. Thank you a lot.